# Blank spaces inserted in Django template empty div

Tags: html, django

I have a Django template which looks like this:

```
<div class = 'description' contenteditable = 'true' placeholder='{{my_placeholder}}'>
</div>
```

The problem is that Django inserts blank spaces in div so that the code below yields

```
A
B
```

instead of `AB`:

```
alert('A' + $('.new').find('.description').html() + 'B');
```

If I rewrite the HTML code as follows (by bring `</div>` on the same line):

```
div class = 'description' contenteditable = 'true' placeholder='{{my_placeholder}}'></div>
```

...the issue goes away. However, I do like the HTML structure where the closing  is on a new line. How can I keep this structure so that the element is really blank and I can see the placeholder value ?

Comment: You can start an HTML comment on the end of the first line, and end it before the closing div tag on the second line ... other than that, there is not much you can do, because that is simply how HTML handles whitespace. (“Django inserts blank spaces” is of course nonsense. You inserted them, in your template.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{% spaceless %}` to remove whitespace between HTML tags:

```
{% spaceless %}
<div class = 'description' contenteditable = 'true' placeholder='{{my_placeholder}}'>
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
```

More about `{% spaceless %}` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless).

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `spaceless` template tag is fine if you've got only few spots with urgent need to eliminate whitespaces, but you should not have too much of them or wrap entire content in `spaceless`.

My point is that it's JavaScript work to be aware that content might contain whitespaces, so just use something like `trim()` function for inner HTML:

```
alert('A' + $('.new').find('.description').html().trim() + 'B');
```

Other than that, indented code with newlines like you've got is perfectly fine for readability purposes, however, I suggest minifying it on production with tools like [django-htmlmin](https://github.com/jdotjdot/django-htmlmin) that will squash your templates when it reaches the user.